# What is the maximum number of characters allowed in a Note field in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

A Text field ([SPFieldText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtext.aspx)) has a limit of 255 characters.  What, if any, is the limit of the Note field ([SPFieldMultiLineText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.aspx))?  The associated documentation on MSDN (linked above) doesn't list these limitations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according to the documentation, the notes field is the same as a field with the type set to note. That is equivalent to the nText field in SQL Server. Here is the limit for that field from the docs:

> Variable-length Unicode data with a
>   maximum length of 2^30 - 1
>   (1,073,741,823) characters.

Here are the links:

The page that you linked:
[spFieldMultilineText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.aspx)
On that page it states

> The SPFieldMultiLineText class
>   corresponds to the Note data type that
>   is specified through the Type
>   attribute of the Field element.

Following the link to the Field element takes you to [Field Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx)

Looking at the Type property, we see this:

> Note   Allows users to enter multiple
>   lines of text. This field is not
>   sortable or groupable. All text is
>   defined to be straight ASCII
>   characters without HTML markup.
>   Anything that looks like HTML markup
>   or a URL is simply quoted (for
>   example, Server.HTMLEncode) to look
>   like straight text. The control for
>   editing this format is a simple
>   TEXTAREA block. Use the NumLines
>   attribute to specify the number of
>   lines to display. Corresponds to the
>   ntext SQL data type and represented by
>   the SPFieldMultiLineText class."

Specifically of interest is **"...Corresponds to the ntext SQL data type..."**

A quick google for "ntext SQL data type" takes you to [nText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Do you have a link that shows that a Note field will be placed in an nText field? I'd just like to have something in writing that shows this is something I can count on (within reason, of course).

Comment: I would be clear however that I have never tested anything like this limit. It might be worth your effort to try some really big text just to have empirical evidence that the limit is at least more than 255 because I think there was a time when it was capped at 255.